# i18n is not working after update nuxt to 3.8.0

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt3, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

after I updated my nuxt framework to 3.8.0 and updated my i18n library to 8.0.0.
and I added it to the module in "nuxt.config.ts"

```
  modules: ['@nuxtjs/i18n'],
```

after I write i18n config in "nuxt.config.ts":

```
  i18n: {
locales: [
    {
        code: 'fa',
        iso: 'fa-IR',
        name: 'Farsi',
        file: 'fa-IR.json',
        dir: 'rtl',
    },
    {
        code: 'en',
        iso: 'en-US',
        name: 'English',
        file: 'en-US.json',
        dir: 'ltr',
    },
],
defaultLocale: 'fa',
detectBrowserLanguage: false,
langDir: "lang",
vueI18n: {
    legacy: false,
    fallbackLocale: 'en',
}
```

}

I got this error about i18n:

```
 ERROR  Cannot start nuxt:  input.includes is not a function   
at normalizeWindowsPath (node_modules/.pnpm/pathe@1.1.1/node_modules/pathe/dist/shared/pathe.92c04245.mjs:2:24)
```

and some other node-module errors.

any idea how can I fix this??

Comment: Share more details about your problem.

Comment: I share more detail about my problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay, I can fix the problem first of all update your i18n dependency after that create a new file called i18n.config.ts in there, I write this code:

```
export default defineI18nConfig(() => ({
legacy: false,
locale: 'en',
messages: {
  en: {
    welcome: 'Welcome'
  },
  fr: {
    welcome: 'Bienvenue'
  }
}}))
```

At last, in nuxt.config.ts I called it

```
    i18n: {
    vueI18n: './i18n.config.ts'
}
```

you can check the i18n website to understand better structure of how it's work https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/